# Memcpy() works on out of bounds memory?

Tags: c, memcpy, segmentation-fault

I have been playing around with the idea that memcpy() could be used for malevolent purposes. I made several test applications to see if I could "steal" data in memory from different regions. I have tested three regions thus far, heap, stack, and constant( read only ) memory. The constant memory was the only one to crash in my tests, provoking an error from MinGW.

Here is an example to illustrate my latest test :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

void removeTerminatingCharacters( char ** string, const int length )
{
    int i = 0;

    for ( ; i < length; ++i )
        if ( !( *string )[i] )
            ( *string )[i] = '0';

    return;
}

int main()
{
    int * naive = malloc( sizeof( int ) );
    *naive = 0;

    char * stolenData = malloc( 2000 );

    memset( stolenData, 0, 2000 );
    memcpy( stolenData, naive, 1999 );
    removeTerminatingCharacters( &stolenData, 2000 );

    printf( "%s\n", stolenData );

    free( stolenData );
    return 0;
}
```

Output :

```
0000-0:0Væ1lDk¦#:00000[æ0`Dk00p,:0-0:0MAIN=Computer0USERNAME=JohnDoe0USERPRO
FILE=C:\Users\JohnDoe0WATCOM=C:\watcom0windir=C:\Windows00?æ1+Ik?000S?000000
00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
00??????????????????????????000000                          00000000 000000?0?0?
00000000000 0 0 ?0000000000 0000000000 0000 00000???????????????????????0???????
                        0        00000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000
000000000000000000abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz000000ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0000
0000â000000Ü0£0P00000000000è0î0Ä 0000000000¬0000000000¦0000¦00000aßGpSsµtFTOd8fe
ä?:0ú?:0-?:0T?:0)?:0`?:0£?:0-?:0p?:0?:0??:0+?:08?:0T?:0¦?:0µ?:0²?:0¶?:03?:0D?:0R
?:0ä :0- :0+ :0a :0v :0?!:0^!:0q!:0ë!:0ñ!:0+!:0±!:0¤":0P":0g":0ó":0¦":0+":0¦":0?
#:0.#:0B#:0W#:0x#:0ë#:00000ALLUSERSPROFILE=C:\ProgramData0APPDATA=C:\Users\Chris
topher\AppData\Roaming0asl.log=Destination=file0CLASSPATH=.;C:\Program Files (x8
6)\Java\jre6\lib\ext\QTJava.zip0CommonProgramFiles=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common
 Files0CommonProgramFiles(x86)=C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files0CommonProgram
W6432=C:\Program Files\Common Files0COMPUTERNAME=COMPUTER0ComSpec=C:\Windows\sys
tem32\cmd.exe0FPPUILang=en-US0FP_NO_HOST_CHECK=NO0HOMEDRIVE=C:0HOMEPATH=\Users\C
hristopher0HuluDesktopPath=C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local\HuluDesktop\instan
ces\0.9.13.1\HuluDesktop.exe0LOCALAPPDATA=C:\Users\JohnDoe\AppData\Local0LOG
ONSERVER=\\COMPUTER0NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS=20OnlineServices=Online Services0OOBEUI
Lang=en-US0OS=Windows_NT0Path=.;F:\CodeBlocks\MinGW\bin;F:\CodeBlocks\MinGW;C:\M
inGW\bin;C:\MinGW;C:\Windows\System32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\wbem;C:\Pro
gram Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Program Files (x86)\Com
mon Files\Microsoft Shared\Windows Live;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1
.0;c:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;c:\Program Files
(x86)\Common F0Uô1m+k
```

My code isn't pretty, but it demonstrates my point. As you can see, the data is mostly garbage values, but there are a few interesting strings thrown in from the heap.

My primary question is why doesn't this action cause a memory access violation error?

Comment: It makes incredibly little sense to "steal" from your own process.  You have unfettered access to any valid virtual memory address, plenty to choose from.  Make this work on *another* process for a real exercise.

Comment: @Hans Heartbleed begs to differ...

Comment: @Konrad - Ugh, ought to obvious that it is always easy when you know how to do it.  You didn't two days ago.

Comment: @Hans OP's question specifically asks that, though (last sentence). The question doesn't mention Heartbleed but it might as well.

Comment: BTW, [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)'s `memcheck` can detect this kind of errors.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Memory access violation errors are caught by virtual memory hardware, when you access an unmapped page. Not every address which is out of bounds is in an unmapped page. Pages are generally of equal sizes. A typical page size if 4096 bytes. (Page sizes are hardware-specific: some chips have memory management that allows for programmable page sizes, and even mixtures of different page sizes for different areas of memory.) Sometimes only part of a page contains valid data. It's not possible for just a fragment of a page to be unmapped, so the part which contains garbage is also mapped. Also, memory managers like `malloc` do not always give memory back to the operating system; they keep free areas for re-use. Those areas are valid memory (mapped pages).  Also, making up pointer values, you can, by fluke, simply end up going beyond out-of-bounds, and can "land" in memory that corresponds to a valid object.

This is just how it works on your PC, with hits virtual memory OS. Virtual memory is not ubiquitous. On computers without virtual memory (nowadays, small embedded systems), you can access any location in memory. However, accessing certain areas may have side effects that change the state of hardware (namely I/O registers).  Some address ranges may trigger a "bus error" type CPU exception because no hardware exists for that range, and so the access request times out. Other than that, as far as valid program memory goes, it is not protected from out-of-bounds accesses.

Operating systems without memory protection were used for early interactive systems in the 1960's. That history then repeated itself when personal microcomputers appeared: again, they had operating systems without memory protection, due to small memories and unsophisticated CPU's.   On these operating systems, applications often stomped over each other's memory spaces, leading to frequent crashes. (Imagine that with your `memcpy`, you not only copy your own out-of-bounds area, such as some malloc block which was previously freed, but also an area from a completely different running program.)  Users sometimes spotted patterns, like when certain programs were loaded into memory in certain orders, there were fewer problems, or so-called "conflicts" between applications.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it does can be used to malevolent purposes, but not in the way you may be thinking.

The memory your application read and write is your process' virtual memory, it is not the physical memory. You can't even know in what address of the physical memory yours or any application really is, only the system kernel knows that.

You cannot interact with active memory from other processes without proper permission and use of syscalls aswell.

You can howover, read the garbage left in unmapped memory areas that were once used by other processes, and you may even stumble in sensitive information left there, like passwords, certificate keys or personal stuff the user typed at some point, but you are on highly volatile grounds, the information there is most likely corrupted and there is no easy way to seek specific pieces of information.

Here is an article about that: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/29019/are-passwords-stored-in-memory-safe

Answer (score 1):

You must not try to access out of bounds memory.
Accessing memory you must not access results in **Undefined Behavior**.
Anything may happen.

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to "steal" the memory. But that's not something you should rely on and write your code based on that.

Answer (score 0):

`memcpy()` doesn't do any bounds check, the programmer has to take care of it. In your case, it causes a `heap overflow`.

This pretty much sums up the consequences of a `heap overflow`:
https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Heap_overflow

**Description**

> A heap overflow condition is a buffer overflow, where the buffer that
>   can be overwritten is allocated in the heap portion of memory,
>   generally meaning that the buffer was allocated using a routine such
>   as the POSIX malloc() call.

**Consequences**

> 1. Availability: Buffer overflows generally lead to crashes. Other attacks leading to lack of availability are possible, including
>      putting the program into an infinite loop.
> 2. Access control (memory and instruction processing): Buffer overflows often can be used to execute arbitrary code, which is
>      usually outside the scope of a program's implicit security policy.
> 3. Other: When the consequence is arbitrary code execution, this can often be used to subvert any other security service.

**Avoidance and mitigation**

> 1. Pre-design: Use a language or compiler that performs automatic bounds checking.
> 2. Design: Use an abstraction library to abstract away risky APIs. Not a complete solution.
> 3. Pre-design through Build: Canary style bounds checking, library changes which ensure the validity of chunk data, and other such fixes
>      are possible, but should not be relied upon.
> 4. Operational: Use OS-level preventative functionality. Not a complete solution.

**Discussion**

> Heap overflows are usually just as dangerous as stack overflows.
>   Besides important user data, heap overflows can be used to overwrite
>   function pointers that may be living in memory, pointing it to the
>   attacker's code.
>   Even in applications that do not explicitly use
>   function pointers, the run-time will usually leave many in memory. For
>   example, object methods in C++ are generally implemented using
>   function pointers. Even in C programs, there is often a global offset
>   table used by the underlying runtime.

Answer (score 0):

To answer your question of "why doesn't this action cause a memory access violation error?", the answer is that it's because the memory in the area for the `naive` allocation has been allocated to the process.  Probably it's memory that the C runtime has prepared for further possible `malloc()` requests.

On most desktop systems, the smallest unit of memory protection is a page, which can vary in size but will often be in the range of 4KB or so. You might well have run into a memory access violation if your read request were larger (but still maybe not - the heap might be much larger than your small allocation). Then again, your allocation could come near then end of a page and hit an access error right away (debug allocators will sometimes do this purposefully to help catch errors).

Answer (score -1):

`memcpy` can't realistically be used for "malevolent" purposes. The only memory that `memcpy` can access is the memory belonging to your own process (which you own, anyway). If you screw up your own memory, your program takes the fall, but the OS will protect all other processes (and you cannot touch their memory spaces without `mmap` or similar).

Most of those "interesting strings" are *environment variables* set by the OS and passed to your program.

Comment: Again, Heartbleed begs to differ.

Comment: @KonradRudolph: Uhh, Heartbleed is a programming error that causes a process to reveal its own memory. This isn't `memcpy`'s fault; the same happens every day with dumb `strcpy` calls. `memcpy` itself has no malicious properties!

Comment: The point is that memcpy (through a programming error) is used for malevolent purpose here. OP asked specifically why an invalid memcpy doesn't cause segfaults here, which would have prevented the malicious usage.